# linked image under shadow not clickable

Tags: html, css

I have a large image at the top of my website. I set a dummy div with inset shadow over it. The problem is that the image is a link and must be clickable but the shadow `div` overlays it and prevents that.

You can see my issue in this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d2sTD/17/)**

HTML :

```
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="shadow"></div>
    <div id="img">
         <div id="dummy"></div>
         <a href="#">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/300"/>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#menu {
    width:100%;
    background-color:blue;
    height:60px;
}
#wrap {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}

#shadow {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 15px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0px -10px 15px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 15px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0px -10px 15px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    z-index:5;
}
#img{
    width:100%;
    max-width:700px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
#dummy {
    width:100%;
    padding-top:30%;
}
#img a {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:2;
}
#img a img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
#content {
    width:100%;
    height:1000px;
}
```

I need the image to be clickable keeping the responsive effect.

Comment: You are overlaying the shadow div over the `a` so what do you expect?

Comment: Can't you move the shadow effect from `#shadow` to the `#img` div?

Comment: @Niklas the proble is that the shadow will go under the img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `pointer-events` to `none` on the `#shadow div`

[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d2sTD/23/)

**CSS**

```
#shadow {
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

[**Browser Support**](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events) is IE11 and modern browsers

Comment: This seems very interresting, the second solution doesn't seem to work. shadows of #menu and #content seem to prevent clicking on the image.

Comment: Great, I'll use this with a fallback with the solution provided by enguerranws.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it with this `HTML` structure. Basically, you can't click on an element that is under another.

I updated your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/d2sTD/18/

In a word : I changed the HTML so the shadow is in your `<a>` element.

**Re-Ordered HTML**

```
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="wrap">
    <a href="#" id="shadow"></a>
    <div id="img">
         <div id="dummy"></div>
         <img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/300"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for adding the html part, I'm at work and quite busy :)

Comment: That seems to be a good alternative for me event though it is not SEO friendly, the designer insists for his shadow... thx